# HTML JavaScript DOM manipulation innerHTML clear

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a simple game that modifies my HTML and keeps track of the keys that I'm typing. When I have a certain score, the keys that I'm typing should be cleared from my paragraph element, but it's not clearing. I'm using innerHTML and setting it equal to an empty string. It never clears though.

```js
var losses = 0;
var guessesLeft = 10;
var guesses = guessesLeft;    

document.onkeypress = function(event) {

  var userChoice = event.key;
  console.log("guesses" + guesses);

  if (guesses === guessesLeft) {
       console.log("Will this work" + userChoice);
       document.getElementById('guess').innerHtml = "";
       var newContent = document.createTextNode(userChoice); 
  } else {
       var newContent = document.createTextNode(', ' + userChoice);
  }
  console.log("newContent" + newContent[0]);
  var newEl = document.createElement('span').appendChild(newContent);
  document.getElementById('guess').appendChild(newEl);

  if (guesses === 0) {
      losses++;
      document.getElementById('losses').innerHTML = ("Losses: " + losses);
      guesses = guessesLeft;
   }
};
```

```html
<div class="container"> 

<div class="row"> 

    <div class="col-lg-12 jumbotron">

         <h1> The Psychic Game </h1>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-4 one"> 



    </div>

    <div class="col-le-4 content"> 

        <p> Guess what letter I'm thinking of? </p> 

        <p id="wins"> Wins: </p>

        <p id="losses"> Losses: </p>

        <p id="left"> Guesses Left:  </p>

        <div> 
            <p> Your guesses so far: <span id="guess"> </span></p>

        </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you know that you can  format html and javascript code on stackoverflow such that it run in the browser?

Comment: `guessesLeft` never gets decremented.

Comment: `newContent` is defined and used in different scopes.

Comment: There are basic logical errors here - that are made apparent by your console log statements. I'm not sure why didn't see that.

Comment: Also, `innerHtml` is not the same as `innerHTML`

Comment: Wow, changed innerHtml to innerHTML and that made a world of difference. Thanks!

Comment: @CameronTharp JavaScript is super case-sensitive. Next time, make sure that when you're reviewing your code, you don't overlook a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the modified code. All I have changed is innerHtml to innerText and added guesses-- in the else part of if (guesses === 0) condition.

I hope this helps.

```js
var losses = 0;
var guessesLeft = 10;
var guesses = guessesLeft;    

document.onkeypress = function(event) {

  var userChoice = event.key;
  console.log("guesses" + guesses);

  if (guesses === guessesLeft) {
       console.log("Will this work" + userChoice);
       document.getElementById('guess').innerText = "";
       var newContent = document.createTextNode(userChoice); 
  } else {
       var newContent = document.createTextNode(', ' + userChoice);
  }
  console.log("newContent" + newContent[0]);
  var newEl = document.createElement('span').appendChild(newContent);
  document.getElementById('guess').appendChild(newEl);

  if (guesses === 0) {
      losses++;
      document.getElementById('losses').innerHTML = ("Losses: " + losses);
      guesses = guessesLeft;
   }
else
 guesses--;
};
```

```html
<div class="container"> 

<div class="row"> 

    <div class="col-lg-12 jumbotron">

         <h1> The Psychic Game </h1>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-4 one"> 



    </div>

    <div class="col-le-4 content"> 

        <p> Guess what letter I'm thinking of? </p> 

        <p id="wins"> Wins: </p>

        <p id="losses"> Losses: </p>

        <p id="left"> Guesses Left:  </p>

        <div> 
            <p> Your guesses so far: <span id="guess"> </span></p>

        </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Adding the decremented guess made the guesses left go down by two instead of one. Fixing the innerHtml to innerHTML was really what I needed.